# Loading and modifying svg within Inkscape plugin

Tags: python, plugins, inkscape

I am currently writing an Inkscape plugin using Python. Within this plugin, I would like to load a template (an existing svg) from the plugin folder and access some objects within this template by name or key. Then I would like to change the border and/or fill color of the object and add some text to it. How would I do this using the python scripting interface of inkscape? I found just a few examples (see below) on how to write a plugin for inkscape, but they all work on existing, already opened documents.

1. http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/write-inkscape-extension-create-multiple-duplicates/
2. http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Script_extensions
3. http://ospublish.constantvzw.org/blog/tools/inkscape-plugins-in-python
4. http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Generating_objects_from_extensions
5. http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/PythonEffectTutorial

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)?

```
t = etree.parse("path/test.xml")
```

You could then either

1. manipulate the properties of `t` directly -- this can be done from python without actually opening inkscape. Your tree could be saved with `t.write("filename")`
2. add  `t` to the currently open document using `self.document.getroot().append(t)`

Also, this is not what you asked for, but may come in useful: an inkscape plugin that allows you to write short python snippets from within Inkscape: http://www.smanohar.com/inkscape.php